# Why wont my Android app start after swipe from recent apps and relaunched after install from Google Play Store?

Tags: android, crash, proguard, samsung-galaxy

This is happening on a Samsung Galaxy s10 phone. The app crashes only when downloaded from the play store, opened, swiped from recent apps list, and re-opened. Crashes on re-open. The icon on the splash screen becomes very small and app crashes at the splash screen. The app did not do this in any testing or debugging. This isn't registering anywhere as a crash. Any idea what is wrong and how to fix this?

The only thing I could find was that it was a possible pro-guard issues but pro-gaurd is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I updated proguard last night with the following code and re-released the app. It appears to be working now in case this helps anyone else:

```
-keep public class 
com.errolapplications.mypackage.myapp
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type
```